# Does "half [something]" need a hyphen?

Tags: grammar, hyphens

Example sentence:

> I couldn't understand his half-question, half-statement.

I did a [Google Book](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22half-question,%20half-statement%22&client=ubuntu&hs=eiX&tbm=bks&ei=tCEhXKf7KoqM8wXMlbCQBA&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwinpb7kiLnfAhUKxrwKHcwKDEIQ8tMDCGo&biw=1855&bih=984&dpr=1) search, and I found out that both usages exist.

Maybe both are right? Or only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not **need** one, which is not to say that it could not or does not benefit from one.